# How to add my app icon in contact list of users' android phone

Tags: java, android

I just finished the development of my app. Its a chat app. Now i want to add my app icon in contact list of phone like Facebook, Google and Whatsapp icon is there. I want exactly like this:

[image]

Means if anybody from my contacts is using my app, icon of my app should be visible with the name in my contacts list. If anybody has any idea, please help me to do this.
thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe for applications to show up in Contacts like the above example, they must also be added in the 'Accounts' section in the settings menu on Android.

You can find more about how exactly to do that here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/package-summary.html

Comment: @ A_Kiniyalocts : Exactly this has to be done.. Would you any example hot to add app in 'Accounts' section in the settings menu on Android.

Comment: I found this: http://www.finalconcept.com.au/article/view/android-account-manager-step-by-step-2  Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks... this should help :)

Comment: This link is not working. Kindly advise other sources for having workable code.

Comment: I have added custom mime type in android contacts list. After a long research i decided to share this with you guys, i have tested this on all Android cell phone including android 9.0  here is link 'https://github.com/soogoodadnan/custom-mime-type'