# how to add my application in android contact and open my application view from there

Tags: android

Can any one give me sample code for display application icon inside android contact list. and also want to open my application from there.

I have tried below links.
[How to add my app icon in contact list of users' android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25029855/how-to-add-my-app-icon-in-contact-list-of-users-android-phone)

[Display the app icon if the contact is associated with the application in phone address book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21701017/display-the-app-icon-if-the-contact-is-associated-with-the-application-in-phone)

but not working properly.

I have also read on developer.android.com but I need sample code.

Comment: Have you found any solution to this?